# Multiple Excel Files as Separate Sheets Using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Most of the articles I'm seeing either:
a) Combine multiple excel single-sheet workbooks into one master workbook with just a single sheet or;
b) Split a multiple-sheet excel workbook into individual workbooks.

However, my goal is to grab all the excel files in a specific folder and save them as individual sheets within one new master excel workbook. I'm trying to rename each sheet name as the name of the original file.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

file = "C:\\File\\Path\\"
filename = 'Consolidated Files.xlsx'
pth = os.path.dirname(file)
extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(pth, '*xlsx'))

w = pd.ExcelWriter(file + filename)

for f in files:
    print(f)
    df = pd.read_excel(f, header = None)
    print(df)
    df.to_excel(w, sheet_name = f, index = False)
   
w.save()
```

How do I adjust the names for each sheet? Also, if you see any opportunities to clean this up please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rename sheet with special characters because `f` is full path and file name. You should use only filename to names sheetname, Use `os.path.basename` to get file name and use `split` to seperate file name and extension.

```
for f in files:
    print(f)
    df = pd.read_excel(f, header = None)
    print(df)
    
    # Use basename to get filename with extension
    # Use split to seperate filename and extension
    new_sheet_name = os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0]
    
    # 
    df.to_excel(w, sheet_name = new_sheet_name , index = False)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to put my solution here as well, just in case it would be useful to anyone.

Thing is, I wanted to be able to recall where the end sheet came from. However, source workbooks can (and likely will) often have same sheet names like "Sheet 1", so I couldn't just use sheet names from original workbooks. I also could not use source filenames as sheet names since they might be longer than 31 character, which is maximum sheet name length allowed by Excel.

Therefore, I ended up assigning incremental numbers to resulting sheet names, while simultaneously inserting a new column named "source" at the start of each sheet and populating it with file name concatenated with sheet name. Hope it might help someone :)

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

files_input = glob(r'C:\Path\to\folder\*.xlsx')

result_DFs = []

for xlsx_file in files_input:
    file_DFs = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file, sheet_name=None)
    # save every sheet from every file as dataframe to an array
    for sheet_DF in file_DFs:
        source_name = os.path.basename(xlsx_file) + ":" + sheet_DF
        file_DFs[sheet_DF].insert(0, 'source', source_name)
        result_DFs.append(file_DFs[sheet_DF])

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Path\to\resulting\file.xlsx') as writer:
    for df_index in range(len(result_DFs)):
        # write dataframe to file using simple incremental number as a new sheet name
        result_DFs[df_index].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(df_index), index=False)
        # auto-adjust column width (can be omitted if not needed)
        for i, col in enumerate(result_DFs[df_index].columns):
            column_len = max(result_DFs[df_index][col].astype(str).str.len().max(), len(col) + 3)
            _ = writer.sheets[str(df_index)].set_column(i, i, column_len)
```